# jqgrid - beforeSearch and afterSearch function are not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to display a progress bar when user tries to filter data in jqgrid. But, the beforeSearch and afterSearch functions are not triggered.

I tried to follow the documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching but, not sure what I am missing...

Here is the fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/14f3Lpnk/1/

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>

var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
        {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"blah",note:"stuff",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}        
    ];
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    ignoreCase: true,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
       colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
           {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
           {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
           {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number"},
           {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}        
       ],
       pager: "#pager",
       viewrecords: true,
       autowidth: true,
       height: 'auto',
       caption: "Test Grid",
        beforeSearch: function () {
            alert('Filter Started');            
        },
        afterSearch: function () {
            alert('Filter Complete');            
        }
}).jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beforeSearch` and `afterSearch` are callback functions of `filterToolbar` method and not the grid itself. So you should use there in the following way

```
.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    defaultSearch: "cn",
    beforeSearch: function () {
        alert('Filter Started');            
    },
    afterSearch: function () {
        alert('Filter Complete');            
    }
});
```

See the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/14f3Lpnk/2/